# Show an underscore variable in console

Tags: javascript, web, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I set an underscore variable with:

```
<% var myVar = 1 %>
```

And I showed it using:

```
<% console.log(myVar) %>
```

What could I use to display myVar directly from the web browser console?

Comment: what do you mean by displaying it directly? also for the record you are not using anything related to underscore in that code so it's just javascript ;)

Comment: When you say "I showed it using `console.log(myVar)`", does that not do what you want? if you want to interact with it in the browser console, if the variable is defined globally you should have access to it.

Comment: What means those closures <% %> ?

Comment: @Pabs123: Looks like something from an Underscore template to me.

Comment: You can't. `_.template` converts your template text to a function so you'll have something like `function() { var myVar = 1; ... }` and you can only access `myVar` from inside the function.

Comment: Yes, it is a template. I added that lines into a template. Ok @muistooshort, clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: you can't.

**Long answer**: when you compile an Underscore template, you get a function back. Everything in your template is inside that function. For example, if you say this:

```
var t = _.template('<% var v = 11; %>');
```

and then look at `t.source` (which [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) conveniently sets for you), you'll see something like this:

```
function(obj) {
    // Boilerplate set up stuff...
    with(obj||{}) {
        __p+='';
        var v = 11; // <-------------- There's your <%...%>
        __p+='';
    }
    return __p;
}
```

so your `var myVar` is inside the template function and `myVar` only exists within the scope of that function and you can't get at it from outside the function.